# how to join custom table in sales order table \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, repository

> i want to join custom table in repository in magento 2

> but i tried

> this tutorial (blog)

https://fishchenko.com/blog/magento-2-join-table-in-orderrepositorygetlist-custom-field/

it was not clear

is anyway to join custom table in orderRepository ?